# Join completable future to current thread on exception

Tags: java, completable-future

I have a method call that dispatches a request and asynchronously waits for the response. Once a response comes in, it fires a callback to process the result.

However, if something fails (wrong response or some other failure) I want to rethrow the exception in the calling thread.

```
dispatcher.dispatch(json)
.whenComplete((responseString, throwable) -> responses.handle(responseString));
```

Rethrowing the exception in the lambda expression will obviously not work, since it's in a different thread. So something along the lines of

```
dispatcher.dispatch(json)
.whenComplete((responseString, throwable) -> responses.handle(responseString))
.joinExceptionally(throwable -> throw throwable);
```

This call can not be blocking either. In other words, is it possible to throw an exception in the calling thread once the completable future completes exceptionally, without blocking?

Comment: Just as an aside: `I have a method call that dispatches a request and asynchronously waits for the response`  This is almost always an error in design.  If all you do is wait for another thread to finish, you might as well execute the task in the first thread of execution, thus saving the overhead of using a separate thread and the IPC.

Comment: @markspace This is not an error in design. The main thread needs to continue with other tasks. The response comes in once the other tasks have been completed. Sorry if that was not clear

Comment: How is the main thread supposed to continue with other tasks when it throws the exception of the asynchronous job at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's basically **impossible**.

You want to handle the request asynchronously, so the request must be handled in another thread. You alse want the Exception to be thrown in the calling thread so the exception must be thrown in the same thread (because exception are propagated through the call stack) which contract to previous requirement.

Usually a dispatcher is use only for dispatching request, it should not be  used to handle exceptions.You'd better use `CompletableFuture`'s built in feature to handle excepitons like `CompletableFuture.handle(BiFunction<? super T, Throwable, ? extends U> fn)`.